# A JNI error has occured when running exe file

Tags: java, jar, exe, java-14, java-runtime-compiler

So I just converted a jar file into an exe file.
My Jar file seems to run smoothly and the code is executed as intended

However when I run my .exe file I get an error window saying "A JNI error has occured. check your installations"

I run JDK 14.01. for my project with JRE 1.8.0_261
As far as I have tried, it does not seem to be a problem with difference in versions of JDK/JRE

Comment: how did you make exe file from jar?

Comment: @zabaykal I used Launch4j. You can output your jar file as exe through this system

Comment: you use javafx for ui?

Comment: @zabaykal I use javax.swing

Comment: did you try to choose JNI GUI in "Header type" ?

Comment: @zabaykal   I am trying. It now tells me to enter a "class path" ? What class path is referred here?

Comment: to the main class

Comment: @zabaykal I cant reference the mainclass as a file. And I am firstly using my .jar file as a basis. Wouldnt this confuse the system? Shouldnt the jar file reference be enough?

Comment: I don't really know, just try it, I did have the same problem but with javafx, and JNI GUI made it works

Comment: @zabaykal Well it is not possible to find my main.class in the file-locater.